# Script for conversion audio files to mp3 recursively in another folder with same names of sub folders

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I have this script for conversion of video files to another folder with same hierarchy. This works fine.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
find . \( -name '*.mkv' -o -name '*.mpg' -o -name '*.3gp' -o -name '*.m4v' -o -name '*.avi' \) -print | while read i ;do
mkdir -p ./converted`dirname "${i:1}"`
    #avidemux2.7_qt5 --load "$i" --run ./to-mp4.py --save ./converted"${i:1:-4}".mp4 --quit
    cp "$i" ./converted"${i:1:-4}".mp4
    echo "$i" ./converted"${i:1:-4}".mp4 >> list
echo $i >> ./converted/done.txt
done
find ./ -type f \( -iname \*.idx2 -o -iname \*.stat \) -delete
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

I am trying ffmpeg to convert audio files in the same manner but it does not work. Many unwanted folders like MP3. and MP3v are created and only a few files are converted. The file names are cut partially showing errors like this.

```
achi.amr: No such file or directory
```

while the file name is `ammachi.amr`.

The script is:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
find ./ -type f \( -name '*.wav' -o -name '*.amr' \) -print | while read i ;do
mkdir -p ./MP3`dirname "${i:1}"`
    ffmpeg -i "$i" -f mp2 "MP3/${i%.*}.mp3"
    echo "'$i'" ./MP3"${i:1:-4}".mp3 >>list
    done
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

@Wayne Vosberg thanks for the trouble. As suggested by Wayne Vosberg. I ran the script for error.log with and without the ffmpeg line of the script commented.

Relevant part of the logs:

```
relevent lines of error.log with the ffmpeg line commented
+ mkdir -p ./MP3/z
+ mkdir -p ./MP3/z
+ mkdir -p ./MP3/z
+ mkdir -p ./MP3/
+ mkdir -p ./MP3/v
+ mkdir -p ./MP3/v
+ mkdir -p ./MP3/v
+ mkdir -p ./MP3/v
+ mkdir -p ./MP3/v
+ mkdir -p ./MP3/
+ mkdir -p ./MP3/

+ echo './z/cd ef.amr' './MP3/z/cd ef.mp3'
+ echo './z/cd ef-5.amr' './MP3/z/cd ef-5.mp3'
+ echo './z/cd ef-4.wav' './MP3/z/cd ef-4.mp3'
+ echo './cd ef-5.amr' './MP3/cd ef-5.mp3'
+ echo './v/cd ef-1.amr' './MP3/v/cd ef-1.mp3'
+ echo './v/cd ef-5.amr' './MP3/v/cd ef-5.mp3'
+ echo './v/cd ef-2.wav' './MP3/v/cd ef-2.mp3'
+ echo './v/cd ef-4.wav' './MP3/v/cd ef-4.mp3'
+ echo './v/cd ef-3.amr' './MP3/v/cd ef-3.mp3'
+ echo './abc d.wav' './MP3/abc d.mp3'
+ echo './cd ef-4.wav' './MP3/cd ef-4.mp3'

relevent lines of error.log with the ffmpeg line uncommented
+ mkdir -p ./MP3/z
+ mkdir -p ./MP3/z
+ mkdir -p ./MP3.
+ mkdir -p ./MP3/v
+ mkdir -p ./MP3.
+ mkdir -p ./MP3/v
+ mkdir -p ./MP3.
+ mkdir -p ./MP3/

+ echo ''\''./z/cd ef.amr'\''' './MP3/z/cd ef.mp3'
+ echo ''\''./z/cd ef-4.wav'\''' './MP3/z/cd ef-4.mp3'
+ echo ''\''/cd ef-1.amr'\''' './MP3cd ef-1.mp3'
+ echo ''\''./v/cd ef-5.amr'\''' './MP3/v/cd ef-5.mp3'
+ echo ''\''cd ef-2.wav'\''' './MP3d ef-2.mp3'
+ echo ''\''./v/cd ef-4.wav'\''' './MP3/v/cd ef-4.mp3'
+ echo ''\''/abc d.wav'\''' './MP3abc d.mp3'
+ echo ''\''./cd ef-4.wav'\''' './MP3/cd ef-4.mp3'

+ ffmpeg -i './z/cd ef.amr' -f mp2 './MP3/z/cd ef'
+ ffmpeg -i './z/cd ef-4.wav' -f mp2 './MP3/z/cd ef-4'
+ ffmpeg -i '/cd ef-1.amr' -f mp2 './MP3cd ef-1'
+ ffmpeg -i './v/cd ef-5.amr' -f mp2 './MP3/v/cd ef-5'
+ ffmpeg -i 'cd ef-2.wav' -f mp2 './MP3d ef-2'
+ ffmpeg -i './v/cd ef-4.wav' -f mp2 './MP3/v/cd ef-4'
+ ffmpeg -i '/abc d.wav' -f mp2 './MP3abc d'
+ ffmpeg -i './cd ef-4.wav' -f mp2 './MP3/cd ef-4'
```

I think the ffmpeg command somehow alters the VAR $i as the script works fine with Avidemux and other commands e.g. cp, mv, etc.

Any suggestions or some other script for this purpose.

Comment: Please try to be more descriptive than *"it does not work"*

Comment: @ steeldriver edited for more details. Thanks.

Comment: For one thing, I *think* you want `mkdir -p ./MP3/$(dirname "${i:0}")`

Comment: @Wayne Vosberg  Thanks. Unwanted folders no more but converts only .amr files not the wav files.

Comment: It appears that somehow the ffmpeg changes the variable some how. Hope someone will help.

Comment: Try running the script as `bash -x /path/to/script 1>script.log 2>error.log`  and then review the log files after.

Comment: @Wayne Vosberg thanks for the trouble. As suggested I ran the script for error.log with and without the ffmpeg line of the script commented. I have pasted the relevant part of the logs [here](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/ScG4Cd4F33/)

Comment: Adding a modified script as an answer so it is readable.

Comment: @karel. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With all the suggestions included and more. This script works.

```
#!/bin/bash
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
find ./ -type f \( -name '*.wav' -o -name '*.amr' \) -print | while read i ;do
mkdir -p ./MP3`dirname "${i:1}"`
    ffmpeg -nostdin -i "$i" -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -b:a 192k ./MP3"${i:1:-4}".mp3
    done
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I see is that the script is failing when the parent directory is just `./`. Try this:

```
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
find ./ -type f \( -name '*.wav' -o -name '*.amr' \) -print | while read i
do
    D=$(dirname "$i")

    if [[ ! -d "./MP3/${D}" ]]
    then
        mkdir -p "./MP3/${D}"
    fi

    O="./MP3/${i%.*}.mp3"

    # ffmpeg -i "$i" -f mp2 "${O}"
    ffmpeg -i - -f mp2 "${O}" <"${i}"

    echo "'$i'" "'${O}'" >>list
done
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

Comment: Thanks for attention but same problem remains.

Comment: Can you run with `bash -x /path/to/script 1>script.log 2>&1` and post the output?

Comment: error.log [here](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/vm8FVY8tVY/)

Comment: All file names [here](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/zJF6c4DTRk/)

Comment: `Parse error, at least 3 arguments were expected, only 1 given in string 'd ef-5.amr'` It appears ffmpeg is not expanding the command line as I would expect. I'll add a change to the answer.

Comment: Add `-nostdin` option to ffmpeg command.

Comment: @llogan Thanks it worked.

Comment: @Wayne Vosberg, Thank for the revision. It works.